# Raspberry Pi Node Server not connecting on other machines

Tags: node.js, angularjs, ubuntu, raspberry-pi

I am running ubuntu 18.4 on a raspberry pi 3b+. I am using node to host an angular web app. I have set a static ip on the RPi but cannot access the webapp from my windows machine at http:ipadress. I get 'refused to connect'.

server code:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
http.listen(PORT, "0.0.0.0", () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

netstat:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2142/node
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8081          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2102/ng serve --por
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41804         127.0.0.1:27017         ESTABLISHED 2142/node
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         127.0.0.1:41804         ESTABLISHED 1347/mongod
```

How can I access my node/angular app from another machine!!!
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't taken a look at your code above specifically - I tried to run it but as it is not a minimum working example it failed with `ReferenceError: http is not defined`.  But I'm assuming you know that?

Assuming therefore that the fuller version of your code compiles and the problem is that port 8080 on the Raspberry Pi is closed; then to open it do the following in the Pi terminal:

```sh
sudo apt install ufw
sudo ufw allow ssh
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw allow 8080
```

You can skip line two if you aren't using ssh to access it; this just stops you being thrown off if you are.

The port should now be accessible on your local network (though probably not the internet, depending on how your router is set up).

I found this [Run your Node.js application on a headless Raspberry Pi](https://dev.to/bogdaaamn/run-your-nodejs-application-on-a-headless-raspberry-pi-4jnn) tutorial useful.